# Can't drag and drop files on Discord while running it as administrator

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, discord, regedit

I've recently bought a new PC and I am facing the same issue I had on my laptop.
I remember that I have actually found a solution for this before, but I cannot find it anymore.
So basically, I can't use Push To Talk while running a game as administrator, so I have to use Discord as admin too.
Well, running Discord as admin doesn't let me drag and drop files and I always have to either choose them manually, or just restart whole app.

As I remember, there was a fix that could be done by using Regedit. (I used it on my Windows 8.1 laptop, and it worked)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I actually found the fix for it on accident:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

All I had to do there, was to change EnableLUA value to 0.
I hope that it'll help some people too

Answer (score 0):

i made an account just to add this, and cannot comment because I'm a new account, but doing what OP said will remove the notices for when something needs your permission when making changes to your computer. this is **bad** and poses a high-security vulnerability if suspicious or malicious files get into your machine. as a senior cyber security major, I would not advise that.

I'm personally trying to figure out a fix for this, but this is not it. I may update this when I have found a fix though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to drag and drop IF I do the following.
Click the plus to get the explorer going where you an "open" files, from that explorer album you can drag and drop.